# Output debug package logs inside a file

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm using [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) npm module to log stuff, is there a way to log into a file programmatically?

Right now I'm doing `DEBUG=* node myApp.js > abc.log`, how can I log into abc.log by simply running `DEBUG=* node myApp.js`, while also outputting in stderr?

I didn't find any package doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The package doesn't seem to provide a builtin feature to do this, but it provides you with a hook to customise how logs are emitted.

There is an example in the Readme [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#output-streams).

*Note: the example is a bit confusing because it shows you how to replace writing on stdout with ... writing on stdout using the console !*

So what you should at the startup of the application:

1. Open a stream that writes to a file. [Tutorial here](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-19-nodejs-writable-streams.html) if you need help on this
2. Override the `log.log()` as explained in [the doc](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#output-streams) to write to your file instead of using `console.log()`.

Comment: I have the same problem, how should I override log.log()? I am not able to override it properly though I know how to write to file

Comment: I overrode with `log.log = function(s){writeToFile(s)};` and it works